# Forms for partial attributes of entity in modal Symfony 5

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, symfony5

I have a project where my user table has the fields:

```
id
username
email
password
mother_language
description
image
```

I use : `username`, `email`, `password`, for registration.

After signing up I redirect to a profile page where I have a modal that has only `mother_language` and `desciption`.
Another modal allows only the modification of the image of the same user.

My questions are:

- How can i update only "**separate**" attributes of an entity using a Form Type.
- Since I am trying to make a "**Single Page**" WebApp, Is It possible to render all of my forms into the profile template? ('On a single route')
- what's the optimal workflow for what i'm trying to do?
  My User Controller if it helps:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Repositry\UserRepository;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/profile", name="profile", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
        $user = $this->getUser();
        return $this->render('profile.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'UserController',      // I tried returning forms in this array but got errors
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/profile", name="update", methods={"PUT"})
     * @param Request
     */
    public function updateUser(Request $request) : Response
    {
        $user = $this->getUser()->getId();
        return dump($user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar scenario for one of my projects. You don't need to load multiple forms. The easiest way is to create a separate form type with only the fields you need to update.

My controller looks like this:

```
public function edit(Request $request): Response
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('dashboard');
    }

    return $this->render('user/profile.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

And the UserType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email')
        ->add('name')
        ->add('university')
        ->add('year')
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => User::class,
    ]);
}
```

Without password and other stuff used on registration.

**Note**: I am editing the information of the current user.

Comment: i can't seem to get my head around this form type and how data flows in order to create it in symfony, i just posted another question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67360713/symfony-5-form-variable-does-not-exist    i would appreciate it if you could take a look